# PyQt5 - set toolTip for each QTreeWidgetItem

Tags: tooltip, pyqt5, qtreewidgetitem

I have a GUI that uses a QTreeWidget to load a list of key - value pairs from a JSON file.

My question is if it's possible to set a tooltip for every item (just the keys) of the QTreeWidget?

P.S. I would like to keep the tree widget and do not move to QTreeView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily answer a questions like this by looking at the [documentation for QTreeWidgetItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidgetitem.html):

> void QTreeWidgetItem::setToolTip(int column, const QString &toolTip)
>
> Sets the tooltip for the given column to toolTip.

Which in PyQt5 will simply be:

```
item = QTreeWidgetItem(key)
item.setToolTip(0, 'some text')
```

Comment: Thanks for the example.